# How to know server connection is lost in client side

Tags: c#, android, tcp

I have a tcp server that writes in winforms and a client in android. I connect devices to a wirless network then I disconnect server from this network. However client continue to listen server for a while then it closes its socket. How can I tell client to close socket when server is disconnected from network?

Comment: If your shutting down process of the server is planned, you probably should implement a Method, which is executed before the server shuts down. This Method would broadcast to all connected clients that they need to close their sockets and in return close the socket for the client on server side. If it's not planned and the server shuts down itself you probably have no other chance than to wait for a timeout at clientside

Comment: No it is not a planned shutting down. Must wait until socket close itself :/ Thank you for your response.

Comment: I just found this link where some methods are explained. It's for clients dropping out at server side but you could implement those on server and client, so both sides would handle incorrect closed Sockes. http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html

Answer (score 0):

The reason it happens (if I understand the problem correctly) is that there is not inherent way to know that a connection has been closed, unless you try to send a package. So in your client, if you try to send an empty package over the connection, it will immediately report if the connection has been closed.

This is the reason that Heartbeats exist, and you can configure your socket to use them, or you can have your client periodically (or when needed) attempting to send an empty package and report the status of the connection.

There is an excellent article on CodeProject about this, [see here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37490/Detection-of-Half-Open-Dropped-TCP-IP-Socket-Conne).